# No output when object is pushed to vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

My model is quite simple but I'm having some problems with the vector I'm using.

Basically, I have a Song class that has one playlist, and a Playlist can have multiple track (inside a vector).

```
Song* song = new Song("Rien de rien", "Biggy", 120);
Playlist* playlist;
Track* synthTrack;

playlist->addTrack(synthTrack); // without this line everything works fine
song->setPlaylist(playlist);

cout << "Title " + song->getTitle() << endl;
```

The console isn't giving me any errors, but the `cout` isn't showing up. This happens as soon as I add a track to my playlist.

This is what my Playlist class looks like:

```
class Playlist {
private:

    vector<Track*> tracklist;

public:
    void addTrack(Track* track){
        this->tracklist.push_back(track);
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you post http://sscce.org please?

Comment: Uhm. Do you initialize `playlist` pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Lucian has already given a reasonable start at fixing the problem you've seen, but I'd advocate a somewhat different route. I'd start by getting rid of all the pointers in the relevant code:

```
Song song("Rien de rien", "Biggy", 120);
Playlist playlist;
Track synthTrack;

playlist.addTrack(synthTrack);
song.setPlaylist(playlist);

cout << "Title " << song.getTitle() << "\n";
```

...and:

```
class Playlist {   
    vector<Track> tracklist;    
public:
    void addTrack(Track const &track){
        tracklist.push_back(track);
    }
};
```

Needing pointers is fairly unusual to start with, and when you do need them, you almost certainly want to wrap them in some sort of smart pointer class. In this case, I see no hint that the latter is necessary or probably even useful though.

Comment: +1 for *"Needing pointers is fairly unusual to start with, and when you do need them, you almost certainly want to wrap them in some sort of smart pointer class"*. That's a home run for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm switching from pointers than. Does this also mean I don't need to initialize my objects anymore? Because I noticed you didn't do that in your example while Luchian did.

Comment: @Sled: Objects do need to be initialized, but that will normally happen in the constructor. The client code just supplies parameters to the ctor (and even that when the ctor actually needs data from the client, such as for the `Song` in the code in the answer).

Answer (score 4):

You're invoking **undefined behavior**, meaning anything can happen, by accessing an invalid pointer:

```
Playlist* playlist;
Track* synthTrack;

playlist->addTrack(synthTrack); // using uninitialized pointer
```

should be

```
Playlist* playlist = new Playlist; //initialize playlist here
Track* synthTrack = new Track; //also initialize synthTrack

playlist->addTrack(synthTrack);
```

Comment: `synthTrack` is still uninitialized & unallocated and is a potential UB in making.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Playlist
{
private:
    vector<Track> tracklist;

public:
    void addTrack(const Track& track){
        tracklist.push_back(track);
    }
};


Song song("Rien de rien", "Biggy", 120);
Playlist playlist;
Track synthTrack;

playlist.addTrack(synthTrack);
song.setPlaylist(playlist);

cout << "Title " + song.getTitle() << endl;
```

or if you want to avoid copying use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr